# Change FontSize as per Window size In Data Template in Windows 10 Universal App

Tags: wpf, windows, xaml, win-universal-app

```
I used a Data template and use that Data Template in the List view.i also use a Visual State Trigger for increase and decrease font size so my question is that when the windows state trigger but font size not changed. font size remain same in both mobile view in PC view.

Its my Code:

Data Template:

 <Page.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Name="CustomerListViewTemplate"  x:DataType="data:Customerlistdata">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <TextBlock Grid.Row="0"
                           Text="{x:Bind full_firstname}" 
                           x:Phase="1"  
                           x:Name="product_name_layout"
                           Style="{ThemeResource BaseTextBlockStyle}"
                           TextWrapping="NoWrap" 
                           Foreground="Gray"                                                 
                           Margin="15,10,0,0"

                           />

                <TextBlock  
                            Grid.Row="1"
                            Text="{x:Bind email_id}" 
                            x:Phase="2"
                            Style="{ThemeResource BodyTextBlockStyle}"
                            Margin="15,5,0,10"
                            x:Name="email_id"
                            FontSize="12"
                            Foreground="Gray"/>


            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Page.Resources>



List View:


<ListView x:Name="MasterListView"
                  SelectionMode="Extended"
                  UseLayoutRounding="False"
                  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Enabled"                 
                  BorderBrush="#FFA79E9E"
                  SelectionChanged="OnSelectionChanged"
                  IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                  ShowsScrollingPlaceholders="False"
                  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CustomerListViewTemplate }"
                  ItemClick="OnItemClick"
                  Grid.Column="0"
                  Grid.Row="1"                   
                        >

                <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>

                    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">

                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />

                    </Style>
                </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>

            </ListView>


Visual State:

   <VisualState x:Name="NarrowState">
                    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                        <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0"  />
                    </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Target="MasterListView.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                        <Setter Target="DetailContentPresenter.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                        <Setter Target="MasterColumn.Width" Value="*" />
                        <Setter Target="DetailColumn.Width" Value="0"/>
                        <Setter Target="product_name_layout.FontSize" Value="10"/>

                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
```

so give me suggestion how can i change font size as per the windows size.
i Want to change a Font Size on window size change. i used a built in style in that.Actully I am making a master detail View in windows universal app .all functionality work properly but font size is not changed.

Comment: Is this so you can scale your UI up? Why don't you place your UI in a viewbox and control size using that?

Comment: @joe: I did not get what you want to explain. actually i dont know about View box.so please provide a source code so i can easily understand.and tell me a easy way to make windows universal app responsive in all device .i have been facing many issue regarding UI responsiveness .so please guide me to make a responsive windows universal app.

Comment: and i have tried with viewbox but which is not fitted in my code so please give me way to make font small

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In this situation we can not change the font size of the data template so we need to add two data template 

1) data template for pc

2) data template for mobile

for pc:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
<Page.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Name="CustomerListViewTemplatePC"  x:DataType="data:Customerlistdata">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <TextBlock Grid.Row="0"
                           Text="{x:Bind full_firstname}" 
                           x:Phase="1"  
                           x:Name="product_name_layout"
                           Style="{ThemeResource BaseTextBlockStyle}"
                           TextWrapping="NoWrap" 
                           Foreground="Gray"                                                 
                           Margin="15,10,0,0"

                           />

                <TextBlock  
                            Grid.Row="1"
                            Text="{x:Bind email_id}" 
                            x:Phase="2"
                            Style="{ThemeResource BodyTextBlockStyle}"
                            Margin="15,5,0,10"
                            x:Name="email_id"
                            FontSize="12"
                            Foreground="Gray"/>


            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Page.Resources>
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

for mobile

<Page.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Name="CustomerListViewTemplateMobile"  x:DataType="data:Customerlistdata">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <TextBlock Grid.Row="0"
                           Text="{x:Bind full_firstname}" 
                           x:Phase="1"  
                           x:Name="product_name_layout"
                           Style="{ThemeResource BaseTextBlockStyle}"
                           TextWrapping="NoWrap" 
                           Foreground="Gray"                                                 
                           Margin="15,10,0,0"

                           />

                <TextBlock  
                            Grid.Row="1"
                            Text="{x:Bind email_id}" 
                            x:Phase="2"
                            Style="{ThemeResource BodyTextBlockStyle}"
                            Margin="15,5,0,10"
                            x:Name="email_id"
                            FontSize="12"
                            Foreground="Gray"/>


            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Page.Resources>
-----------------------------------------------------------------

aftre make a  two individual data template then  fire a trigger for both mobile(narrow state) and pc(wide state)


like this...........

<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="PageSizeStatesGroup"
                              CurrentStateChanged="OnCurrentStateChanged">


<VisualState x:Name="NarrowState">
                    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                        <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0"  />
                    </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Target="MasterListView.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                        <Setter Target="DetailContentPresenter.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                        <Setter Target="MasterColumn.Width" Value="*" />
                        <Setter Target="DetailColumn.Width" Value="0"/>

                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>


<VisualState x:Name="WideState">
                    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                        <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0"  />
                    </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Target="MasterListView.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                        <Setter Target="DetailContentPresenter.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                        <Setter Target="MasterColumn.Width" Value="*" />
                        <Setter Target="DetailColumn.Width" Value="auto"/>


                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>


    </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>


-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

then apply data template in the listview like this

 <ListView x:Name="MasterListView"
                  SelectionMode="Extended"
                  UseLayoutRounding="False"
                  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Enabled"                 
                  BorderBrush="#FFA79E9E"
                  SelectionChanged="OnSelectionChanged"
                  IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                  ShowsScrollingPlaceholders="False"
                  ItemTemplate="{`enter code here`StaticResource CustomerListViewTemplate }"
                  ItemClick="OnItemClick"
                  Grid.Column="0"
                  Grid.Row="1"                   
                        >

                    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>

                        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">

                            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"  Value="Stretch" />
                            <Setter Property="FontSize"  Value="10" />
                        </Style>
                    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>

                </ListView>
```